# How can I identifying each checkbox

Tags: reactjs

I am building todoList that when I check the box, the component is disappeared. I tried to identify each checkbox with index!
So, I make state:`checkedItem`, which have a "false or true" state in each checkbox. But, it doesn't render right away.

Here is my code sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/old-voice-6xyovb?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

const todos = [
  { id: 0, value: "Wash the dishes" },
  { id: 1, value: "have lunch" },
  { id: 2, value: "listen to music" },
  { id: 3, value: "running" },
  { id: 4, value: "work out" }
];
export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState(todos);
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = React.useState(
    new Array(todos.length).fill(false)
  );

  const checkHandler = ({ target }, idx) => {
    checkedItems[idx] = !checkedItems[idx];
    setCheckedItems(checkedItems);
    //I want to identify idx ..
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map((todo, idx) => (
        <div key={idx}>
          <span>{todo.value}</span>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checkedItems[idx]}
            onChange={(e) => checkHandler(e, idx)}
          ></input>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you call `setCheckedItems` but you give it the exact same array, so this is not considered a change.

To fix this, make sure you give it a new array:

```
setCheckedItems([...checkedItems]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, I've updated your sandbox with notes and fixes.

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-ioana-b04r8f?file=/src/App.js